# $|xy(x^2-y^2)+yz(y^2-z^2)+xz(z^2-x^2)|\le J (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2$, What is the smallest value of J that allows inequality

Tags: inequality

$\forall (x,y,z)\;\in\;\mathbb R$

$|xy(x^2-y^2)+yz(y^2-z^2)+xz(z^2-x^2)|\le J (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2$

How we can find for the smallest value of "$J$" when providing to inequality

Effort:
I could only show this,after didn't nothing ;

$(a-c)(a-b)(b-c)(a+b+c)=ab(a^2-b^2)+bc(b^2-c^2)+ac(c^2-a^2)$

Comment: See here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h101294

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(c-a)$ instead of $(a-c)$?

Comment: @Yuriy S $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3b-a^3c)=(a+b+c)(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \le b \le c$$$\implies |(a - b)(b - c)| = (b - a)(c - b) \le \left[\frac{(b - a) + (c - b)}{2}\right]^2 = \frac{(c - a)^2}{4} \le \frac{(b - a)^2 + (c -b)^2}{2}$$

$$\implies \left\{ \begin{align} |(a - b)(c - a)(b - c)| \le \frac{(c - a)^3}{4}\\ 3(c - a)^2 \le 2 \cdot [(a - b)^2 + (c - a)^2 + (b - c)^2] \end{align} \right.$$

, or equivalently $$\left\{ \begin{align} |(a - b)(c - a)(b - c)|^2 \le \left[\frac{(c - a)^3}{4}\right]^2\\ \left[\frac{(c - a)^2}{2}\right]^3 \le \left[\frac{(a - b)^2 + (c - a)^2 + (b - c)^2}{3}\right]^3 \end{align} \right.$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have that

$$2|(a - b)(c - a)(b - c)|^2 \le \left[\frac{(a - b)^2 + (c - a)^2 + (b - c)^2}{3}\right]^3$$

Moreover, by using the AM-GM inequality, we have that

$$\left[\frac{(a - b)^2 + (c - a)^2 + (b - c)^2}{3}\right]^3 \cdot (a + b + c)^2 \le \left[\frac{(a - b)^2 + (c - a)^2 + (b - c)^2 + (a + b + c)^2}{4}\right]^4$$

$$\implies 2|(a - b)(c - a)(b - c)|^2 \cdot (a + b + c)^2 \le \left[\frac{3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)}{4}\right]^4$$

$$\implies |(a + b + c)(a - b)(b - c)(c - a)| \le \frac{9\sqrt 2}{32} \cdot (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2$$

The equality sign occurs when $$\left\{ \begin{align} c - b &= b - a\\ \frac{(a - b)^2 + (c - a)^2 + (b - c)^2}{3} &= (a + b + c)^2 \end{align} \right.$$

$$\iff \left\{ \begin{align} b &= \frac{c + a}{2}\\ 2(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca) &= 3[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab + bc + ca)] \end{align} \right.$$

$$\iff \left\{ \begin{align} b &= \frac{c + a}{2}\\ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 8(ab + bc + ca) &= 0 \end{align} \right.$$

$$\iff \left\{ \begin{align} b &= \frac{c + a}{2}\\ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 8(ab + bc + ca) &= 0 \end{align} \right.$$

Plugging in $b = \dfrac{c + a}{2}$ into the second equation and we get that $(a, b, c)$ is proportional to $\left(1 - \dfrac{3\sqrt 2}{2}, 1, 1 + \dfrac{3\sqrt 2}{2}\right)$